# web3j - my ethereum transactions are not being processed / mined / confirmed

Tags: java, kotlin

I only have problems with the smart contract functions which require a gas fees. I am able to call the other functions no problem. Through different posts, I found out that it might have to do with setting the correct gas price. but, even after trying multiple variations for gas prices, I am still stuck. If you have any suggestions, please do type them.

My autogenerated class (name - ContractHex, function being called - registerVote)-

```
package com.kenetic.blockchainvs.block_connector.contract.contract_interface;

import org.web3j.abi.TypeReference;
import org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Address;
import org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Bool;
import org.web3j.abi.datatypes.DynamicArray;
import org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Function;
import org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Type;
import org.web3j.abi.datatypes.generated.Uint256;
import org.web3j.crypto.Credentials;
import org.web3j.protocol.Web3j;
import org.web3j.protocol.core.RemoteCall;
import org.web3j.protocol.core.RemoteFunctionCall;
import org.web3j.protocol.core.methods.response.TransactionReceipt;
import org.web3j.tx.Contract;
import org.web3j.tx.TransactionManager;
import org.web3j.tx.gas.ContractGasProvider;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

/**
 * <p>Auto generated code.
 * <p><strong>Do not modify!</strong>
 * <p>Please use the <a href="https://docs.web3j.io/command_line.html">web3j command line tools</a>,
 * or the org.web3j.codegen.SolidityFunctionWrapperGenerator in the
 * <a href="https://github.com/web3j/web3j/tree/master/codegen">codegen module</a> to update.
 *
 * <p>Generated with web3j version 1.4.1.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public class ContractHex extends Contract {
    public static final String BINARY = "{\n"
            + "\t\"functionDebugData\": {\n"
            + "\t\t\"@_30\": {\n"
            + "\t\t\t\"entryPoint\": null,\n"
            + "\t\t\t\"id\": 30,\n"
            + "\t\t\t\"parameterSlots\": 0,\n"
            + "\t\t\t\"returnSlots\": 0\n"
            + "\t\t}\n"
            + "\t},\n"
            + "\t\"generatedSources\": [],\n"
            + "\t\"linkReferences\": {},\n"
            + "\t\"object\": \"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\",\n"
            + "\t\"opcodes\": \"PUSH1 0x80 PUSH1 0x40 MSTORE CALLVALUE DUP1 ISZERO PUSH2 0x10 JUMPI PUSH1 0x0 DUP1 REVERT JUMPDEST POP PUSH1 0x0 PUSH1 0x2 DUP2 SWAP1 SSTORE PUSH1 0x3 DUP2 SWAP1 SSTORE PUSH1 0x4 SSTORE PUSH2 0x3BE DUP1 PUSH2 0x2F PUSH1 0x0 CODECOPY PUSH1 0x0 RETURN INVALID PUSH1 0x80 PUSH1 0x40 MSTORE CALLVALUE DUP1 ISZERO PUSH2 0x10 JUMPI PUSH1 0x0 DUP1 REVERT JUMPDEST POP PUSH1 0x4 CALLDATASIZE LT PUSH2 0x7D JUMPI PUSH1 0x0 CALLDATALOAD PUSH1 0xE0 SHR DUP1 PUSH4 0x449B6DB2 GT PUSH2 0x5B JUMPI DUP1 PUSH4 0x449B6DB2 EQ PUSH2 0xB8 JUMPI DUP1 PUSH4 0x464D4A92 EQ PUSH2 0xDB JUMPI DUP1 PUSH4 0xA483F4E1 EQ PUSH2 0xEE JUMPI DUP1 PUSH4 0xF5A31579 EQ PUSH2 0xF6 JUMPI PUSH1 0x0 DUP1 REVERT JUMPDEST DUP1 PUSH4 0x68EA0EB EQ PUSH2 0x82 JUMPI DUP1 PUSH4 0xEFCB43C EQ PUSH2 0x8C JUMPI DUP1 PUSH4 0x42CFF738 EQ PUSH2 0xA3 JUMPI JUMPDEST PUSH1 0x0 DUP1 REVERT JUMPDEST PUSH2 0x8A PUSH2 0xFE JUMP JUMPDEST STOP JUMPDEST PUSH1 0x4 SLOAD JUMPDEST PUSH1 0x40 MLOAD SWAP1 DUP2 MSTORE PUSH1 0x20 ADD JUMPDEST PUSH1 0x40 MLOAD DUP1 SWAP2 SUB SWAP1 RETURN JUMPDEST PUSH2 0xAB PUSH2 0x1CB JUMP JUMPDEST PUSH1 0x40 MLOAD PUSH2 0x9A SWAP2 SWAP1 PUSH2 0x312 JUMP JUMPDEST CALLER PUSH1 0x0 SWAP1 DUP2 MSTORE PUSH1 0x20 DUP2 SWAP1 MSTORE PUSH1 0x40 SWAP1 KECCAK256 SLOAD PUSH1 0xFF AND PUSH1 0x40 MLOAD SWAP1 ISZERO ISZERO DUP2 MSTORE PUSH1 0x20 ADD PUSH2 0x9A JUMP JUMPDEST PUSH2 0x8A PUSH2 0xE9 CALLDATASIZE PUSH1 0x4 PUSH2 0x2F9 JUMP JUMPDEST PUSH2 0x22D JUMP JUMPDEST PUSH1 0x3 SLOAD PUSH2 0x90 JUMP JUMPDEST PUSH1 0x2 SLOAD PUSH2 0x90 JUMP JUMPDEST CALLER PUSH1 0x0 SWAP1 DUP2 MSTORE PUSH1 0x20 DUP2 SWAP1 MSTORE PUSH1 0x40 SWAP1 KECCAK256 SLOAD PUSH1 0xFF AND ISZERO PUSH2 0x163 JUMPI PUSH1 0x40 MLOAD PUSH3 0x461BCD PUSH1 0xE5 SHL DUP2 MSTORE PUSH1 0x20 PUSH1 0x4 DUP3 ADD MSTORE PUSH1 0x1B PUSH1 0x24 DUP3 ADD MSTORE PUSH32 0x596F75204861766520416C7265616479204265656E2041646465640000000000 PUSH1 0x44 DUP3 ADD MSTORE PUSH1 0x64 ADD JUMPDEST PUSH1 0x40 MLOAD DUP1 SWAP2 SUB SWAP1 REVERT JUMPDEST CALLER PUSH1 0x0 DUP2 DUP2 MSTORE PUSH1 0x20 DUP2 SWAP1 MSTORE PUSH1 0x40 DUP2 KECCAK256 DUP1 SLOAD PUSH1 0xFF NOT AND PUSH1 0x1 SWAP1 DUP2 OR SWAP1 SWAP2 SSTORE DUP1 SLOAD DUP1 DUP3 ADD DUP3 SSTORE SWAP2 MSTORE PUSH32 0xB10E2D527612073B26EECDFD717E6A320CF44B4AFAC2B0732D9FCBE2B7FA0CF6 ADD DUP1 SLOAD PUSH20 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF NOT AND SWAP1 SWAP2 OR SWAP1 SSTORE JUMP JUMPDEST PUSH1 0x60 PUSH1 0x1 DUP1 SLOAD DUP1 PUSH1 0x20 MUL PUSH1 0x20 ADD PUSH1 0x40 MLOAD SWAP1 DUP2 ADD PUSH1 0x40 MSTORE DUP1 SWAP3 SWAP2 SWAP1 DUP2 DUP2 MSTORE PUSH1 0x20 ADD DUP3 DUP1 SLOAD DUP1 ISZERO PUSH2 0x223 JUMPI PUSH1 0x20 MUL DUP3 ADD SWAP2 SWAP1 PUSH1 0x0 MSTORE PUSH1 0x20 PUSH1 0x0 KECCAK256 SWAP1 JUMPDEST DUP2 SLOAD PUSH1 0x1 PUSH1 0x1 PUSH1 0xA0 SHL SUB AND DUP2 MSTORE PUSH1 0x1 SWAP1 SWAP2 ADD SWAP1 PUSH1 0x20 ADD DUP1 DUP4 GT PUSH2 0x205 JUMPI JUMPDEST POP POP POP POP POP SWAP1 POP SWAP1 JUMP JUMPDEST PUSH1 0x4 DUP2 LT DUP1 ISZERO PUSH2 0x23D JUMPI POP PUSH1 0x0 DUP2 GT JUMPDEST PUSH2 0x2AF JUMPI PUSH1 0x40 MLOAD PUSH3 0x461BCD PUSH1 0xE5 SHL DUP2 MSTORE PUSH1 0x20 PUSH1 0x4 DUP3 ADD MSTORE PUSH1 0x39 PUSH1 0x24 DUP3 ADD MSTORE PUSH32 0x74686520676976656E206E756D62657220697320696E76616C69642061732074 PUSH1 0x44 DUP3 ADD MSTORE PUSH32 0x6865206E756D626572206973206F7574206F662072616E676500000000000000 PUSH1 0x64 DUP3 ADD MSTORE PUSH1 0x84 ADD PUSH2 0x15A JUMP JUMPDEST DUP1 PUSH1 0x1 EQ ISZERO PUSH2 0x2D0 JUMPI PUSH1 0x2 DUP1 SLOAD SWAP1 PUSH1 0x0 PUSH2 0x2C8 DUP4 PUSH2 0x35F JUMP JUMPDEST SWAP2 SWAP1 POP SSTORE POP POP JUMP JUMPDEST DUP1 PUSH1 0x2 EQ ISZERO PUSH2 0x2E9 JUMPI PUSH1 0x3 DUP1 SLOAD SWAP1 PUSH1 0x0 PUSH2 0x2C8 DUP4 PUSH2 0x35F JUMP JUMPDEST PUSH1 0x4 DUP1 SLOAD SWAP1 PUSH1 0x0 PUSH2 0x2C8 DUP4 PUSH2 0x35F JUMP JUMPDEST PUSH1 0x0 PUSH1 0x20 DUP3 DUP5 SUB SLT ISZERO PUSH2 0x30B JUMPI PUSH1 0x0 DUP1 REVERT JUMPDEST POP CALLDATALOAD SWAP2 SWAP1 POP JUMP JUMPDEST PUSH1 0x20 DUP1 DUP3 MSTORE DUP3 MLOAD DUP3 DUP3 ADD DUP2 SWAP1 MSTORE PUSH1 0x0 SWAP2 SWAP1 DUP5 DUP3 ADD SWAP1 PUSH1 0x40 DUP6 ADD SWAP1 DUP5 JUMPDEST DUP2 DUP2 LT ISZERO PUSH2 0x353 JUMPI DUP4 MLOAD PUSH1 0x1 PUSH1 0x1 PUSH1 0xA0 SHL SUB AND DUP4 MSTORE SWAP3 DUP5 ADD SWAP3 SWAP2 DUP5 ADD SWAP2 PUSH1 0x1 ADD PUSH2 0x32E JUMP JUMPDEST POP SWAP1 SWAP7 SWAP6 POP POP POP POP POP POP JUMP JUMPDEST PUSH1 0x0 PUSH1 0x0 NOT DUP3 EQ ISZERO PUSH2 0x381 JUMPI PUSH4 0x4E487B71 PUSH1 0xE0 SHL PUSH1 0x0 MSTORE PUSH1 0x11 PUSH1 0x4 MSTORE PUSH1 0x24 PUSH1 0x0 REVERT JUMPDEST POP PUSH1 0x1 ADD SWAP1 JUMP INVALID LOG2 PUSH5 0x6970667358 0x22 SLT KECCAK256 CALLDATASIZE 0xC7 0xA6 0xEB SWAP1 JUMPDEST 0xFB SWAP12 0xBC 0xBF 0x24 CALLDATASIZE SWAP8 PC PUSH25 0xA32327F0FD4A8648F67281FD07BE0FF4B064736F6C63430008 SMOD STOP CALLER \",\n"
            + "\t\"sourceMap\": \"74:1607:0:-:0;;;272:108;;;;;;;;;-1:-1:-1;313:1:0;297:13;:17;;;325:13;:17;;;353:15;:19;74:1607;;;;;;\"\n"
            + "}";

    public static final String FUNC_ADDMETOVOTEDLIST = "addMeToVotedList";

    public static final String FUNC_GETADDRESSVALUES = "getAddressValues";

    public static final String FUNC_GETPARTY1VOTES = "getParty1Votes";

    public static final String FUNC_GETPARTY2VOTES = "getParty2Votes";

    public static final String FUNC_GETPARTY3VOTES = "getParty3Votes";

    public static final String FUNC_HASALREADYVOTED = "hasAlreadyVoted";

    public static final String FUNC_REGISTERVOTE = "registerVote";

    @Deprecated
    protected ContractHex(String contractAddress, Web3j web3j, Credentials credentials, BigInteger gasPrice, BigInteger gasLimit) {
        super(BINARY, contractAddress, web3j, credentials, gasPrice, gasLimit);
    }

    protected ContractHex(String contractAddress, Web3j web3j, Credentials credentials, ContractGasProvider contractGasProvider) {
        super(BINARY, contractAddress, web3j, credentials, contractGasProvider);
    }

    @Deprecated
    protected ContractHex(String contractAddress, Web3j web3j, TransactionManager transactionManager, BigInteger gasPrice, BigInteger gasLimit) {
        super(BINARY, contractAddress, web3j, transactionManager, gasPrice, gasLimit);
    }

    protected ContractHex(String contractAddress, Web3j web3j, TransactionManager transactionManager, ContractGasProvider contractGasProvider) {
        super(BINARY, contractAddress, web3j, transactionManager, contractGasProvider);
    }

    @Deprecated
    public static ContractHex load(String contractAddress, Web3j web3j, Credentials credentials, BigInteger gasPrice, BigInteger gasLimit) {
        return new ContractHex(contractAddress, web3j, credentials, gasPrice, gasLimit);
    }

    @Deprecated
    public static ContractHex load(String contractAddress, Web3j web3j, TransactionManager transactionManager, BigInteger gasPrice, BigInteger gasLimit) {
        return new ContractHex(contractAddress, web3j, transactionManager, gasPrice, gasLimit);
    }

    public static ContractHex load(String contractAddress, Web3j web3j, Credentials credentials, ContractGasProvider contractGasProvider) {
        return new ContractHex(contractAddress, web3j, credentials, contractGasProvider);
    }

    public static ContractHex load(String contractAddress, Web3j web3j, TransactionManager transactionManager, ContractGasProvider contractGasProvider) {
        return new ContractHex(contractAddress, web3j, transactionManager, contractGasProvider);
    }

    public static RemoteCall<ContractHex> deploy(Web3j web3j, Credentials credentials, ContractGasProvider contractGasProvider) {
        return deployRemoteCall(ContractHex.class, web3j, credentials, contractGasProvider, BINARY, "");
    }

    public static RemoteCall<ContractHex> deploy(Web3j web3j, TransactionManager transactionManager, ContractGasProvider contractGasProvider) {
        return deployRemoteCall(ContractHex.class, web3j, transactionManager, contractGasProvider, BINARY, "");
    }

    @Deprecated
    public static RemoteCall<ContractHex> deploy(Web3j web3j, Credentials credentials, BigInteger gasPrice, BigInteger gasLimit) {
        return deployRemoteCall(ContractHex.class, web3j, credentials, gasPrice, gasLimit, BINARY, "");
    }

    @Deprecated
    public static RemoteCall<ContractHex> deploy(Web3j web3j, TransactionManager transactionManager, BigInteger gasPrice, BigInteger gasLimit) {
        return deployRemoteCall(ContractHex.class, web3j, transactionManager, gasPrice, gasLimit, BINARY, "");
    }

    public RemoteFunctionCall<TransactionReceipt> addMeToVotedList() {
        final Function function = new Function(
                FUNC_ADDMETOVOTEDLIST,
                Arrays.<Type>asList(),
                Collections.<TypeReference<?>>emptyList());
        return executeRemoteCallTransaction(function);
    }

    public RemoteFunctionCall<List> getAddressValues() {
        final Function function = new Function(FUNC_GETADDRESSVALUES,
                Arrays.<Type>asList(),
                Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(new TypeReference<DynamicArray<Address>>() {
                }));
        return new RemoteFunctionCall<List>(function,
                new Callable<List>() {
                    @Override
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    public List call() throws Exception {
                        List<Type> result = (List<Type>) executeCallSingleValueReturn(function, List.class);
                        return convertToNative(result);
                    }
                });
    }

    public RemoteFunctionCall<BigInteger> getParty1Votes() {
        final Function function = new Function(FUNC_GETPARTY1VOTES,
                Arrays.<Type>asList(),
                Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(new TypeReference<Uint256>() {
                }));
        return executeRemoteCallSingleValueReturn(function, BigInteger.class);
    }

    public RemoteFunctionCall<BigInteger> getParty2Votes() {
        final Function function = new Function(FUNC_GETPARTY2VOTES,
                Arrays.<Type>asList(),
                Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(new TypeReference<Uint256>() {
                }));
        return executeRemoteCallSingleValueReturn(function, BigInteger.class);
    }

    public RemoteFunctionCall<BigInteger> getParty3Votes() {
        final Function function = new Function(FUNC_GETPARTY3VOTES,
                Arrays.<Type>asList(),
                Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(new TypeReference<Uint256>() {
                }));
        return executeRemoteCallSingleValueReturn(function, BigInteger.class);
    }

    public RemoteFunctionCall<Boolean> hasAlreadyVoted() {
        final Function function = new Function(FUNC_HASALREADYVOTED,
                Arrays.<Type>asList(),
                Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(new TypeReference<Bool>() {
                }));
        return executeRemoteCallSingleValueReturn(function, Boolean.class);
    }

    public RemoteFunctionCall<TransactionReceipt> registerVote(BigInteger num) {
        final Function function = new Function(
                FUNC_REGISTERVOTE,
                Arrays.<Type>asList(new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.generated.Uint256(num)),
                Collections.<TypeReference<?>>emptyList());
        return executeRemoteCallTransaction(function);
    }
}
```

the class I use to access the wrapper class functions -

```
package com.kenetic.blockchainvs.block_connector.contract.contract_interface

import android.util.Log
import org.web3j.crypto.Credentials
import org.web3j.protocol.Web3j
import org.web3j.protocol.core.DefaultBlockParameterName
import org.web3j.protocol.http.HttpService
import org.web3j.tx.ChainIdLong
import org.web3j.tx.RawTransactionManager
import org.web3j.tx.gas.ContractGasProvider
import org.web3j.tx.gas.StaticGasProvider
import org.web3j.utils.Convert
import java.math.BigDecimal
import java.math.BigInteger
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

private const val TAG = "VoteContractDelegate"

class VoteContractDelegate() {
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------contract-elements
    // TODO: get this from data store
    private val USER_PRIVATE_KEY =
        "66c53799ee0c63f2564305e738ea7479d7aee84aed3aac4c01e54a7acbcc4d92"
    private val ROPSTEN_INFURA_URL = "https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/c358089e1aaa4746aa50e61d4ec41c5c"
    private val CONTRACT_ADDRESS = "0x84D46ba7aAac6221DF9038d3Ccf41F1cd46001aF"

    private val credentials = Credentials.create(USER_PRIVATE_KEY)

    private val web3j: Web3j = Web3j.build(HttpService(ROPSTEN_INFURA_URL))
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------works-as-intended

    // TODO: set correct value
    private val gasPrice: BigInteger = Convert.toWei("150", Convert.Unit.GWEI).toBigInteger()

    //this gas limit value is from deployment and has to be constant
    private val gasLimit = BigInteger.valueOf(4_000_000L)

    private val gasProvider: ContractGasProvider = StaticGasProvider(gasPrice, gasLimit)

    private var contract: ContractHex =
        ContractHex.load(
            CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
            web3j,
            RawTransactionManager(web3j, credentials, ChainIdLong.ROPSTEN),
            gasProvider
        )

    // TODO: this is the problem function...
    fun casteVote(party: PartyEnum): String {
        return try {
            Log.d(TAG, "started casteVote, Vote to be caste for ${party.name}")
            val remoteCall = contract.registerVote(
                BigInteger.valueOf(
                    when (party) {
                        PartyEnum.ONE -> 1
                        PartyEnum.TWO -> 2
                        PartyEnum.THREE -> 3
                    }
                )
            )
            Log.d(
                TAG,
                "remote call generated, \nhashcode = ${remoteCall.hashCode()}\n${remoteCall.toString()}"
            )
            val asyncSent = remoteCall.sendAsync()
            Log.d(TAG, "async sent")
            val gasUsedForTransaction = asyncSent.get(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES).gasUsed.toString()
            Log.d(TAG, "get passed")
            gasUsedForTransaction
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            e.message.toString()
        }
    }
}
```

the github link for this project - [android kotlin project](https://github.com/Vaishnav-Kanhirathingal/BlockChain-VS)

Comment: You need to get the gas price from some provider, you can't rely on a static value as it keeps changing throughout the day. You can see the current gas price on ropsten right now - https://dashboards.anyblock.tools/ethereum/ethereum/ropsten/gas-metrics/?currency=usd&chunk_size=hour&interval=latest_week&speed=slow&tx_type=NATIVE&tx_currency=usd&tx_chunk_size=hour

Comment: Also, do your transaction submit to the blockchain? It shouldn't matter whether gas prices high are or low, the transaction has to submit and the network can then process it or reject it, but you should be able to get back a transaction hash, which you can then use to find your submitted transaction on https://ropsten.etherscan.io

Comment: @LoXatoR if the transaction should show in the network while it is in progress in the ropsten website then, my answer is no. I can't see any transactions (not even the failed one). Do you have any other way in which I can send the transaction or is there anything wrong you can see here?

Comment: Well, that means that your transaction isn't being posted to the network. I haven't called smart contracts in Java so I don't really what's going on here, sorry. But I assume your problem is that you are either not calling the function correctly (in JS, you either send() or call() functions, and transactions are of type send(), since you are sending a transaction to the network). OR if your smart contract function call is correct, then your transaction object is not built correctly and the provider through which you send it, rejects it before sending it along to the network.

Comment: @LoXatoR the class I have at the top is an autogenerated class generated using the web3 CLI. So, I'm assuming that the autogenerated class is not a problem. the only remaining place for a problem to form is in the second class I have provided (atleast thats what I'm assuming). Also, about the send() function, all tutorials for web3-java had the send function similar to web3js (I'm assuming). can you just verify if my gas pricing is good enough for a transaction? That way I can look for other problems and not have to focus on having that right.

Comment: I mean if I understand the gas code correctly, you are setting 150 GWEI, which is more than enough to make a transaction. I don't undestand the `4_000_000L` gas limit bit. Rule of thumb for a transaction is that it should be greater than 21000 in case of ETH transactions. Sorry, can't be more of help :/

Comment: 4_000_000L is the same as 4,000,000. just easier to read and kotlin allows it. so, I have to assume something else is the problem. still, you were more help than other. So, have an upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I had to go for a raw transaction instead of the autogenerated functions.

My assumption is that either the web3j library isn't best suited for test net transactions

Or, the `executeRemoteCallTransaction` is faulty because even with my current settings, it won't perform the transactions.

---

For how I solved this issue,

Just copy/modify the function's autogenerated method from the java file such that you get only the encoded function.

Then, use the encoded function as the data for the raw transaction.

The example below isn't the best. but, at the very least it executes.

And, of course, you'll have to optimize the function according to your needs.

---

The auto generated function that's suspected to be faulty -

```
public RemoteFunctionCall<TransactionReceipt> registerVote(BigInteger num) {
    final Function function = new Function(
            FUNC_REGISTERVOTE,
            Arrays.<Type>asList(new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.generated.Uint256(num)),
            Collections.<TypeReference<?>>emptyList());
    return executeRemoteCallTransaction(function);
}
```

My test function that returns an encoded function string -

```
String TAG = "Test";

public String testFunction(Long num) throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    Function function = new Function(
            "registerVote",
            Arrays.<Type>asList(new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.generated.Uint256(num)),
            Collections.<TypeReference<?>>emptyList());

    String encodedFunction = FunctionEncoder.encode(function);
    return encodedFunction;
}
```

My final function that executes -

```
private const val TAG = "VoteContractDelegate"

class VoteContractDelegate() {
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------project-elements
    private val CONTRACT_ADDRESS = "0x84D46ba7aAac6221DF9038d3Ccf41F1cd46001aF"

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------credentials
    private val USER_PRIVATE_KEY =
        "66c53799ee0c63f2564305e73bea7479d7aeewraed3aac4c01e54a7acbcc4d92"
    //use your own private key above.
    private val credentials = Credentials.create(USER_PRIVATE_KEY)

    private val ROPSTEN_INFURA_URL = "https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/c358089e1aaa4746aa50e61d4ec41c5c"
    private val web3j: Web3j = Web3j.build(HttpService(ROPSTEN_INFURA_URL))

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------gas-controller
    private val gasPrice: BigInteger = Convert.toWei("200", Convert.Unit.GWEI).toBigInteger()
    private val gasLimit = BigInteger.valueOf(40000)
    private val gasProvider: ContractGasProvider = StaticGasProvider(gasPrice, gasLimit)

    private var contract: ContractHex = ContractHex.load(
        CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
        web3j,
        RawTransactionManager(web3j, credentials, ChainIdLong.ROPSTEN),
        gasProvider
    )

    fun testingFunction() {
        val nonce = web3j
            .ethGetTransactionCount(credentials.address, DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST)
            .send()
            .transactionCount
        // TODO: change bigint to 1
        Log.d(TAG, "nonce for transaction nonce = $nonce")

        val rawTransaction = RawTransaction.createTransaction(
            ChainIdLong.ROPSTEN,
            nonce,
            gasLimit,
            CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
            BigInteger.ZERO,             //value for the transaction. the function doesn't accept ether. so, zero
            Test().testFunction(1),      //this returns the encoded function using the function encoder
            gasPrice,                    //this is the 'maxPriorityFeePerGas' I set this high to be on the safe side
            gasPrice                     //this is the 'maxFeePerGas'         I set this high to be on the safe side
        )

        val signedTransaction =
            TransactionEncoder.signMessage(rawTransaction, ChainIdLong.ROPSTEN, credentials)
        Log.d(TAG, "signed transaction byte array = ${signedTransaction.toList()}")

        val hex = Numeric.toHexString(signedTransaction)
        Log.d(TAG, "hex of a signed transaction for value one - $hex")

        Log.d(TAG, "transaction test started...")      //transaction hash gets generated below.

        val transactionHash = web3j.ethSendRawTransaction(hex).send().transactionHash
        Log.d(TAG, "transactionHash = $transactionHash")
    }
}
```